# How to fix npm start errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I just downloaded a dashboard that uses react.js modules so when get to the dashboards source folder and try to run the command 'npm start' I get the error below:

I tried the following commands but it couldn't work

```
sudo npm -g uninstall node
npm install node
npm cache clean
sudo npm install -g npm
npm install

npm start
npm ERR! path /home/lamechd/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/lamechd/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/lamechd/.npm/_logs/2019-06-04T09_51_23_106Z-debug.log
```

NB/ Iam using manjaro Operating System based on archlinux

Comment: have you run `npm install`?

Comment: Check that `/home/lamechd/package.json` exist. Be sure no error in file name `package.json`

Comment: I solved it thanks guys the problem was that another localhost was already started